# ‎$C‎^{*}$-algebra‎

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let‎‎‎‎ ‎$ A , B $ ‎be‎ ‎$C‎^{*}$-‎algebra ‎with ‎identity ‎and‎ ‎$ ‎\varphi :‎ A‎ ‎‎\longrightarrow B‎ ‎‎ $ ‎is  a‎‎ ‎linear map and for all $ a \in A  \quad  ‎\parallel‎‎ ‎\varphi ( a ) ‎‎‎‎‎‎‎\parallel =‎ ‎‎\parallel a‎ ‎‎\parallel‎‎ $, ‎so ‎that  ‎$ ‎\forall a‎ \in  ‎A‎ $‎,‎‎ ‎$ ‎\varphi (‎ ‎a‎^{*} )  = ‎‎\varphi  (‎ a‎ ‎)‎^{*} ‎‎\qquad‎‎ ,  ‎\varphi (‎ ‎1‎_{A} )‎ =‎ ‎1‎_{B}‎‎ ‎‎‎‎‎$‎.

‎**prove‎:**

> ‎$ ‎\varphi (‎ ‎A‎_{+} )‎ ‎‎\subset ‎B‎_{+}‎‎ $‎‎

(‎ $ A‎_{+}‎$  ‎is‎  ‎the ‎set ‎of ‎positive ‎elements ‎of  ‎‎$‎‎A‎$‎) ‎‎

> positive ‎element means:‎

‎$$a=a‎^{*},~‎ ‎‎ ‎\sigma (‎a‎)‎ ‎‎\subseteq [‎0,‎‎‎‎\infty‎)‎ $$

Comment: Is there anything to the uniformity mapping that you haven't said already?  Do we know that $\varphi$ is linear?  Is $\varphi$ a [$*$-homomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C*-algebra#Abstract_characterization)?

Comment: $\varphi  $ is leaner map.

Comment: I have no idea what "uniformity mapping" or "leaner map" is supposed to mean.

Comment: excuse me. i edited it.

Comment: Great, now it makes sense

Comment: So doesn't $‎\varphi$ assume to be a algebra homomorphism? (i.e.$‎\varphi(xy)=‎\varphi(x)‎\varphi(y)$)

Comment: I can`t  open the part " see here". please help me.

Comment: by this condition:  $ \forall a‎ \in  ‎A‎ $‎,‎‎ ‎$   ‎\varphi (‎ ‎a‎^{ * } )  = ‎‎\varphi  (‎ a‎ ‎)‎^{ * } $ , $ \varphi $  is * -homomorphism.

Comment: You can't access there? I paste it here again, you can try again.
https://noncommutativeanalysis.wordpress.com/2012/12/20/advanced-analysis-notes-15-c-algebras-square-root/

Comment: Why ‎$\varphi (‎ ‎a‎^{ * } ) =‎‎\varphi  (‎ a‎ ‎)‎^{ * }$ implies $‎\varphi$  is $ * $-homomorphism??
A $ * $-homomorphism still need this condition "$‎\varphi(xy)=‎\varphi(x)‎\varphi(y)$"! Is there any theorem say that?

Comment: If the link still don't work. You can find any book relevant to C*-algebra or Gelfand-Naimark theorem. ex: C*-algebras by Example, I.4 Positive Elements

Answer (score 1):

If you means $\varphi$ is a $∗$-homomorphism. Then for any $a\in‎ ‎A‎_{+}$, then ‎$\varphi (a)=\varphi (‎ \sqrt{a}^2 )=‎\varphi (‎ \sqrt{a})^2 $, so $\varphi (a)\in B_{+}$ (since it is a square). So  $‎\varphi (‎ ‎A‎_{+} )‎ ‎‎\subset ‎B‎_{+}‎‎$.

If you are confused with what is "$\sqrt{a}$", see [here](https://noncommutativeanalysis.wordpress.com/2012/12/20/advanced-analysis-notes-15-c-algebras-square-root/).

Comment: I don't suspect $\varphi$ needs to be a $\ast$-homomorphism (otherwise the isometry assumption is redundant).